# Low FPS for Object detection on CPU

Tags: python, cpu, object-detection, yolov8

I am working on Person detection task on CPU, i have to do this task on CPU only.
I have trained YOLO v8 but it is slow on cpu, please suggest me, how to boost up FPS, so, it can run perfectly, or you can suggest me another algorithms, so i can work on that as well.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from ultralytics import YOLO
import socket
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

detection_colors = [0, 255, 0]
classNames = ["person"]
count = 0
count_off = 0
count_frame=0
skip_frames=4

model = YOLO("weights/yolov8n.onnx")

frame_wid = 800
frame_hyt = 480

def hooter_delay():
    time.sleep(10)
    message="OFF"
    threading.Thread(target= data_sender,args=(message,), daemon=True).start()
    
    
def making_rect(bb, clsID):
    global count
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(int(bb[0]), int(bb[1])),(int(bb[2]), int(bb[3])),[0, 255, 0],2)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX
    cv2.putText(frame,classNames[int(clsID)] + "%",(int(bb[0]), int(bb[1]) - 10),font,1,(255, 255, 255),2,)
    count+=1
    if count == 1:
        message="ON"
        threading.Thread(target= data_sender,args=(message,), daemon=True).start()
        threading.Thread(target= hooter_delay, daemon=True).start()

def data_sender(message):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as data_socket:
        data_socket.connect(('192.168.1.70', 502))
        data_socket.send(message.encode())
        print(message)

def process_frame(frame):
    global count_frame,skip_frames, count
    count_frame +=1
    frame = cv2.resize(frame,(frame_wid,frame_hyt))
    if skip_frames > 0 and count_frame%skip_frames==0:
        detect_params = model.predict(source=frame, conf=0.25, save=False, show=False, verbose=False, classes=[0], iou=0.7, device="CPU")
        DP = detect_params[0].numpy()
        if len(DP) != 0:
           for i in range(len(detect_params[0])):
                boxes = detect_params[0].boxes
                box = boxes[i]
                clsID = box.cls.numpy()[0]
                conf = box.conf.numpy()[0]
                bb = box.xyxy.numpy()[0]
                if classNames[int(clsID)] == 'person':
                    if conf >= 0.45:
                        threading.Thread(target= making_rect,args=(bb, clsID,), daemon=True).start()
        else:
            count = 0
##            count_off += 1
##            if count_off == 1:
##                message = 'OFF'
##                threading.Thread(target= data_sender,args=(message,), daemon=True).start()
    return frame

video_source = "rtsp://admin:Shiv@1301@192.168.1.250/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0"
##video_source = "rtsp://admin:Pass@123@192.168.1.64/H264?ch=1&subtype=0"
##video_source=0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = frame[:,150:]
        if not ret or frame is None:
            print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        else:
            processed_frame = executor.submit(process_frame, frame).result()
        if processed_frame is not None:
            cv2.imshow("ObjectDetection", processed_frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Application is, whenever my algorithm sees any person as an object it will send "ON" message to specific IP Address and then after 10 seconds "OFF" message will be send to that particular IP Address.

Please, help me out